# How do I set a product image?

Tags: 6, ubercart

When creating a product node for Ubercart, how do I set the product image?

I am using the following code to create a product node.

```
$node = new stdClass();

$node->name = "Title";
$node->title = $node->name;
$node->body = "Lorem Ipsum"; 
$node->type = "configurator_product"; //my own product class
$node->created = time();
$node-> changed = $node->created;
$node->promote = 0;
$node->sticky = 0;
$node->format = 2;
$node->status = 1;
$node->language = "en";
$node->default_qty = 1;
$node->sell_price = 55.00;
$node->shippable = 1;
```

The product node has a *field_image_cache* field which expects a file (extensions: png, gif, jpg, jpeg). I tried to set this field.

```
$node->field_image_cache = "Path/to/module/Images/image1.jpeg";
// Results in Fatal error: Cannot unset string offsets in 
// path/to/modules/cck/content.module on line 1248

$node->field_image_cache[0]['value'] = "Path/to/module/Images/image1.jpeg";
// No errors, but when viewing the product in store administration there is no image
```

What is the correct way to set an image for a product?

Answer (score 1):

```
  $img_file = file_get_contents("Path/to/module/Images/image1.jpeg");
  $img_file = file_save_data($img_file, file_directory_path() .'/path2imagefield_folder/image1.jpeg', FILE_EXISTS_RENAME);
  $node->field_image_cache = array(
    array(
      'fid' => 'upload',
      'title' => basename($img_file),
      'filename' => basename($img_file),
      'filepath' => $img_file,
      'filesize' => filesize($img_file),
    ),
  );
```